# Animal Tattoos - How would that be possible?

Tags: fauna, body-modification

Is it possible for animals with fur/scales/feathers to get tattoos? If the answer is 'yes', then how?

Comment: Humans have fur and get tattoos. Often they get tattoos in places they are furry!

Comment: Are you asking "who will make them" or "can fur (hair), scales, feathers be colorized in particular way for prolonged time"?

Comment: I'm asking both.

Comment: Also [How would tattoos fare on reptilian scales?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4807)

Answer (score 2):

It's possible and indeed common practice to apply a code to the body of a horse which is completely readable, even with the fur and is completely permanent.  The process is called freeze marking or freeze branding and relies on liquid nitrogen.  More details are available here; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze_brand

I doubt it would work for an animal covered in scales.  The closest thing I can think of for that is tortoises with owners details painted onto their shell.

Comment: Race horses are also tattooed on their lips, for identification: http://www.horse-races.net/library/lip-tattoos.htm